# I want to adjust the output

Tags: java

With the following java code I edit the data and the result looks like this

```
[Aba , heim , 2001436]
[Eler , Nord , 2002696]
[Abe , walde , 1999297]
[Mann , Bor , 2005161]
```

Unfortunately this does not help me to get any further, I would like to change the output so that it looks like this

```
Aba ~ heim ~ 2001436
Eler ~ Nord ~ 2002696
Abe ~ walde ~ 1999297
Mann ~ Bor ~ 2005161
```

Here is the code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Test {

    public static <R> Stream<R> streamOf(Iterator<R> it) {
        return StreamSupport.stream(Spliterators.spliteratorUnknownSize(it, Spliterator.ORDERED), false);
    }

    public static <R> Stream<R> reverse(Stream<R> s) {
        return streamOf(s.collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayDeque::new)).descendingIterator());
    }

    public static String[] reorder(String[] row) {
        int skip = row.length > 2 ? 2 : 1;
        String last = reverse(Stream.of(row).skip(skip).map(s -> s.toLowerCase().startsWith("jg.") ? s.substring(3) : s)
                .map(String::trim).filter(s -> !s.isEmpty()).filter(x -> Character.isDigit(x.charAt(0))))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining());

        String[] result = new String[3];
        result[0] = row[0];
        result[2] = last.isEmpty() ? null : last;
        if (skip == 2) {
            result[1] = row[1];
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String str = "Aba ~ heim ~ 436~Jg.2001\n" + "Abe ~ Nord ~ 696 ~Jg.2002\n" + "Eler ~ walde ~297~Jg.1999\n"
                + "Mann ~ Bor~ 161~Jg.2005\n";

        new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str)).lines().filter(l -> !l.isEmpty()).map(l -> l.split("~"))
                .map(Test::reorder).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome Henri2. Have you consider using a data object, containing three strings? Then you can overwrite the toString method to generate an output string in the format that you desire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str)).lines().filter(l -> !l.isEmpty()).map(l -> l.split("~"))
            .map(Test::reorder).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

to

```
new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str)).lines().filter(l -> !l.isEmpty()).map(l -> l.split("~"))
                .map(Test::reorder).map(l->String.join("~", l)).forEach(System.out::println);
```